# Plotly - prevent <a> Tag from open new tab

Tags: anchor, plotly

The x label of my plotly diagram contains a link to the selected data point:

```
let str = '<a href="' + url + '"target=' + '_self' + '>' + cycleStart[1] + '</a>';
```

But the link is always opened in a new tab. I know that the target attribute causes this problem. But as you can see my simple solution is not working. I already searched

```
target="_blank"
```

in the plotly.min js file and changed it into

```
target="_self"
```

Also this does not work for me.
So how can I prevent this  Tag from opening a new tab? I want the url to open in the same window.

Comment: @michealT provide a basic working example with the issue!

Comment: https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/zaXjyW . It's strange that this example works but in my original script a new tab is opened. Of course I did not edit the plotly script. Maybe I make a mistake by building the string? `let url = singledrive_main.htm' + '?cycleid=' +  cycle.id;
                let str = '<a href="' + url + '"target='+'_self'+'>' + cycleStart[1] + '</a>';`

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Not yet. As I sayed, there is no problem in the example. But I do exactly the same in my project. So i guess I did a mistake by building the string: `let url = singledrive_main.htm' + '?cycleid=' + cycle.id; let str = '<a href="' + url + '"target='+'_self'+'>' + cycleStart[1] + '</a>';`